# lateinit property resultReceiver has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm following the guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address) but when I run my app, it crashes with the error

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property resultReceiver has not been initialized at com.imincode.earthlings.view.ui.MainActivity.startIntentService(MainActivity.kt:339)
```

My 339 is the line `putExtra(AppConstants.RECEIVER, resultReceiver)` inside the function below

```
private fun startIntentService() {

    val intent = Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService::class.java).apply {
        putExtra(AppConstants.RECEIVER, resultReceiver)
        putExtra(AppConstants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, lastLocation)
    }
    startService(intent)
}
```

`resultReceiver` is declared as below

```
private lateinit var resultReceiver: AddressResultReceiver
```

Now I don't know how to initialize `resultReceiver`, as it's an `AddressResultReceiver` type which is an inner class as shown in the guide

```
internal inner class AddressResultReceiver(handler: Handler) : ResultReceiver(handler) {

        override fun onReceiveResult(resultCode: Int, resultData: Bundle?) {

            // Display the address string
            // or an error message sent from the intent service.
            var addressOutput = resultData?.getString(AppConstants.RESULT_DATA_KEY) ?: ""
            Timber.d("addressOutput: " + addressOutput)

            // Show a toast message if an address was found.
            if (resultCode == AppConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {
                Timber.d("address found!!")
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now I don't know how to initialize resultReceiver, as it's an AddressResultReceiver type which is an inner class as shown in the guide

[The lateinet property help you avoid null checks when referencing](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables) (`?`)

You initialize the `inner class` like : `YourOuterClass().AddressResultReceiver(yourHandler)`

You can check if initialized or not i.e:

```
 if(!resultReceiver.isInitialized)
    resultReceiver = YourOuterClass().AddressResultReceiver(yourHandler)
```

Comment: resultReceiver doesn't have the method isInitialized... also what should I put for `yourHandler` ? Since `handler` is only declared inside the inner class

Comment: `also what should I put for yourHandler ? Since handler is only declared inside the inner class`  Then you need to remove it from params because you don't need it as parameter !